# Issues with the click of the button in my form

Tags: php, forms

I have a problem with my forms. I create 3 buttons and when I click on one of them, I would like to add "+1" at my stock in function of my ingredient.

But the problem is, when I click on the first button for example, it adds +1, so it's good. But if I click now on the second button (after clicking of 1st button)  it adds +1 again on the element which correspond to my first button. And after I reclick on 2nd button it adds +1 for my second button....

Here my code :

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['salade']) AND $_POST['salade'] == '+') {
    $nom='salade';
    $req=$db->prepare("UPDATE ingredients SET stock = stock +1 WHERE nom =:nom");
    $req->execute(array('nom' =>$nom));
  }
  elseif (isset($_POST['steak']) AND $_POST['steak'] == '+') {
    $nom='steak';
    $req=$db->prepare("UPDATE ingredients SET stock = stock +1 WHERE nom =:nom");
    $req->execute(array('nom' =>$nom));}
  else {
    $nom='cornichon';
    $req=$db->prepare("UPDATE ingredients SET stock = stock +1 WHERE nom =:nom");
    $req->execute(array('nom' =>$nom));
  }
?>
```

Comment: Can you please share the form HTML?

Comment: You have too many unclosed questions, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to separate each button on his form cause when you are submitting the PHP post take everything inside the form so if you hade hidden input he will take it's valued so what are you are doing is you taking the same element over and over again and that is will give you the same result with the three-button and the same if you add a fourth or a fifth for that you need to isolate them each button on his form or to use jquery for treating those things where you have ajax I
 hope my explanation was clear

Comment: It doesnt works. When I reload my site, the increment is still here.

Comment: then what I think you need to go watch a video on youtube type 
Ajax With Multiple Forms And One PHP Processing File  it's a video of 9 min it will explain to you how to what you are wanting to use the same idea on your example and it will works